# Is it possible to put in an array into one row/column with SQL?

Tags: mysql

Working on a feature to have multiple comments to be displayed for the admins.

Currently, the db table has a column that's called admin_comments which records 1 comment at a time (overwriting the previous one).

Question is, does sql allow for recording arrays of string into 1 column? I gather I could use implode with PHP that we're running but how would one separate values later for coherent display?

Or is a separate table the only way to go?

I am just trying to brainstorm this.

Comment: No, there are no arrays in SQL. You should use another table.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to normalize by moving the comments into their own table and keyed to the main table with a foreign key.

You could "hack" it and use one column for several comments by delimiting each comment with a character that won't be used inside any comment. You would then use PHP's `explode` function to create an array of strings:

```
$comments = explode("~", $commentsField); // assumes ~ is the delimiter.
```

I reiterate, this method isn't very nice.